# What kinds of lightsabers (and fighting methods) are available?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

One of the (excellent) videos for Star Wars: The Old Republic showcases a character wielding 2 lightsabers... and one of those is itself a double-bladed lightsaber, allowing for a particularly crazy-looking fighting situation with 3 blades. Is it possible to do this in the game?

More to the point, what lightsaber options are available to Force users?

Comment: Wait, are you talking about the opening cinematic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Number of light sabers depends on your advanced class.

Jedi Guardian - Sith Juggernaut - 1 Lightsaber

Jedi Sentinel - Sith Marauder - 2 lightsabers

Jedi Sage - Sith Sorcerer  - 1 Lightsaber

Jedi Shadow - Sith Assassin - 1 Double

So no, you cant have 3 lightsabers on the same fight.